# DataTable and Kendo Window UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, kendo-ui, kendo-window

i am trying to learn and implement DataTable to my project. Actually i really need DataTable export functionality.

I have a button on my page. Its open Kendo UI Window and everything is quite okay. But when i click the "export excel, export pdf,..." buttons on new window page, export buttons dont work for me.

I think i have a script crash. i have been trying for hours but i couldnt make it. All of your helps will be really appreciated.

// Here is my kendo window code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("myWindow") //The name of the window is mandatory. It specifies the "id" attribute of the widget.
.Title("Login") //set the title of the window
.Content(@<text>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0">
   // my table content
</table>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "tableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "/Scripts/datatables/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
            }
        });
    });

</script>




</text>)
.Draggable() //Enable dragging of the window
.Resizable() //Enable resizing of the window
.Modal(true)
.Visible(false)

)
```

// Kendo's script

```
<script>
    function openWindow() {
        var wdw = $("#myWindow").data("kendoWindow"); //get the Window widget's instance
        wdw.center();
        wdw.open();  //and call its open method

    }
</script>
```

// My button which triggers "openWindow();

```
 <input onclick="openWindow()" value=" Özet Tabloyu Göster " />
```

// DataTable export script

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "tableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "/Scripts/datatables/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using DataTable you can directly export contents of table tag into an excel file. Please refer this [link answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450419/exporting-html-table-into-excel-using-javascript)

Comment: Hi again and thank you for your reply @Nitin Mall, all of my table's dynamic so datatable's feauteres contains my requirements very well.